# To get Users in Realm

Tags: authentication, authorization, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to find users i keycloak which are stored in realm, but it is not returning any users.
It is always returning me null or an empty array.

I tried using the source code:
RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(reamName);
UsersResource usersResource = realmResource.users();
List userss=usersResource.search(username,null,null,null,null,1);

but is not returning me any users instead I have 7 users in realm.

Comment: Is this question related to MongoDB Realm per the tag? If so, can you clarify how Realm (the database) is being used?

Comment: `UserRepresentation user = keycloak.realm(realmName).users().search(username).get(0);` This worked for me.

Comment: @Jay the user is using "Realm" in this context as a Keycloak Realm not a MongoDB realm.